# AWS ec2 windows application not visible after launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've got a windows application that has been deployed to an AWS EC2 instance which has then been configured to run on startup via the task scheduler.  This all works as intended with one exception.  When I remote into the EC2 instance, I can't see the application.  It's running (visible on the task manager) and producing the output as expected but the GUI is not visible and I'd like to be able to see it when I RDP into the instance.

It is being launched via the task scheduler and I can't find anything in the settings to enable the GUI to be visible for the application when I remote into the system.  Is there an EC2 instance setting that needs to be enabled to make this possible?

Comment: That's Windows for you! If it runs as a service, then there is no UI component -- it simply runs in the background. If it is an application that opens a window and interacts with a user, then it isn't really made to be automatically run on startup. When you RDP into a Windows computer (EC2 or not), it logs in as the given user. When you disconnect, it logs you out. Your session is not the same session as where the application is running, so the window won't be visible. Check the documentation of the application to see if they recommend a way to start it in the background and then access the UI

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it was the answer that I was expecting.  The application was designed to run in the background so I doubt that there is a sufficient solution that would work for it.